# Betta fish with bump on his tail

Tags: behavior, diseases, betta

[image]

My betta has got a red lump on his tail that just appeared. I have reviewed many sites but haven't seen anything quite like it. I have had him for about 6 months and he has been very healthy. Now He seems a little sluggish and spends lots of time on the bottom.  When he does swim, he is all over the place then quickly goes back to the bottom. His water temp is good, he gets partial water changes regularly.  Not sure what has caused the bump or the behaviour change.

Comment: I do not know what this is but you described my beta to a T. His started as a little red bump on a one of his bottom fins and since then it has turned white and has continued to grow slowly. If you have found anything out let me know.